# MVC textbox list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want my mvc to act the same way as my classic asp example.  My classic asp example is simple.
I can add as many values to list box with np. my mvc only allows one then replace each value everytime I add one.  How can I get my mvc to work like Classic asp.net.

Classic Asp.net

aspx.

```
 <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="StoreToAdd" ></asp:textbox>
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddStore" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddStore_Click1" />
```

backend c#

```
  protected void btnAddStore_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstStores.Items.Add(StoreToAdd.Text);
        StoreToAdd.Text = "";

    }
```

MVC view

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")) { 
 @Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.StoreToAdd, new { Style = "height:20px; " })
 <div align="center">
  <input type="submit" name="addS" id="addS" value="Add" 
        /></div>

 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.lstStores, new     
 new MultiSelectList(Model.lstStores),
  new { style = "width:225px;height:255px" })

}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
    {

        model.lstStores = new List<string>();
        model.lstStores.Add(model.StoreToAdd);
       return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doing this in your controller:

```
model.LstStores = new List<string>();
```

Wouldn't you expect that to reset your list each time?

Perhaps you could check if the list has already been instantiated first, and just add the new item if it has:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
    {
        if (model.lstStores != null)
        {
            model.lstStores.Add(model.StoreToAdd);
        }
        else
        {
            model.lstStores = new List<string>();
            model.lstStores.Add(model.StoreToAdd);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```